# Time-invariant Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, arithmetic, invariance

I was wondering if it is safe to assume that

$$
(1/t)y'(t) + (1/t)y(t) = 0
$$

is a time-varying differential equation.

I would say these (1/t) factors cancel out and make the eq. time invariant. But I was not completely sure.

Comment: What do you mean by time-varying? The solution changes with time?

Comment: For time invariant, a time delay would give what was expected, just delayed. On the other hand, time-varying can handle time delays this way. If factoring out the (1/t) is a safe assumption, then it is time invariant; otherwise, it is not. My question was if this cancellation is allowed?

Comment: Your equation can be rewritten as $\dfrac1t \big(y'(t) + y(t)\big) = 0$ ie $y'(t) + y(t) = 0$ as $\dfrac1t \ne 0 \, \forall \, t$

Comment: Thank you sir. Just as a follow-up, should we worry for particular values of t, like t = 0. Or should we clearly mention for all t greater than 0?

Comment: The ODE isn't defined at $t=0$ so this should be stated in the question. If you still worry about it, I suggest you assume continuity at $t = 0$ because the ODE is equivalent to $y'(t) + y(t) = 0$.

Comment: Unless the equation, $y'(t)+y(t)=0$, upon solving with its necessary initial condition yields only a trivial solution (e.g. $y=constant$) then it is 'time-varying'. This is regardless of the distracting $1/t$ term that should be multiplied out.